# Using FlatFileItemReader and MultiResourceItemReader with SynchronizedItemStreamReader

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

Trying to process multiple csv files using MultiResourceItemReader and reading each file using FlatFileItemReader. When trying to process step with task executor, getting two issues:

1. ReaderNotOpenException. This issue occurs because multiple files being processed in multithreaded environment and there may be situation where one thread tries to read from a csv file which was closed by some other thread. To solve this issue I am thinking to use SynchronizedItemStreamReader as below:

```
MultiResourceItemReader<activeForecast> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        resourceItemReader.setResources(DataSyncUtils.getFileName(activeForecastFilePath));
        resourceItemReader.setDelegate(activeForecastReader());
        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<activeForecast> synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
        synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(resourceItemReader);
        return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
```

2. FlatFileItemReader gives inconsistent results when used with task executor. So to overcome this I am planning to use SynchronizedItemStreamReader as suggested here: [Can I use FlatfileItemReader with Taskexecutor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998974/can-i-use-flatfileitemreader-with-taskexecutor)

My question: **Do I need to use SynchronizedItemStreamReader with both FlatFileItemReader and MultiResourceItemReader? If yes why and how?**

```
    @Bean("activeForecastitemReader")
    @StepScope
    public MultiResourceItemReader<activeForecast> activeForecastItemReader() {
        MultiResourceItemReader<activeForecast> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        resourceItemReader.setResources(DataSyncUtils.getFileName(activeForecastFilePath));
        resourceItemReader.setDelegate(activeForecastReader());
        return resourceItemReader;
    }

    public FlatFileItemReader<activeForecast> activeForecastReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<activeForecast> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        flatFileItemReader.setName("activeForecast-Reader");
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(activeForecastLineMapper());
        flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        flatFileItemReader.setSaveState(false);
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MultiResourceItemReader` reads files in sequence. So it does not make sense to me to use it in a multi-threaded step.

If you want to go parallel with multiple threads, I believe a partitioned step is a better option. In this cases, you make each worker thread process a distinct file.